# How to do one to one mapping in hibernate using annotation

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-onetomany

I quite new to hibernate. Im trying to do one to one (inner join)mapping using annotaion . But Im getting result of all recored
Please help me to come from this.

i want expect the result of this query

**select * from employee_1 e join employee_sal es on e.id=es.id;**

Below are my code and table structure.

Employee.java

```
    import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    @Entity
    @Table(name="employee_1")
    public class Employee {
        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
    private int id;
        @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

   @OneToOne(mappedBy="employee")
    public EmployeeSal employeeSal;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return id+name;
    }

}
```

**EmployeeSal.java**

```
 import javax.persistence.Column;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
    import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
    import javax.persistence.Table;
    @Entity
    @Table(name="employee_sal")
    public class EmployeeSal {

        @Id
        @Column(name="id")
        private int id;
        @Column(name="sal")
        private int sal;
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="id")
        public Employee employee;
        public int getSal() {
            return sal;
        }
        public void setSal(int sal) {
            this.sal = sal;
        }
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return id+sal+"";
        }
    }
```

**Application.java**

```
import org.hibernate.Session;

import hibernate.HibernateUtil;

    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            session.beginTransaction();
            System.out.println(session.createCriteria(Employee.class).list());

        }
    }
```

**HibernateUtil.java**

```
package hibernate;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;


    public class HibernateUtil {
      private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
      private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
          try {
            // Create registry
            registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .configure()
                .build();

            // Create MetadataSources
            MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

            // Create Metadata
            Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

            // Create SessionFactory
            sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (registry != null) {
              StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            }
          }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
      }

      public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
          StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
      }
    }
```

**mapping XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">


<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test_details</property>
        <property name="format_sql">false</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" >update</property>


        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">7</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">53</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">1000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>

          <mapping class="Employee"/>
          <mapping class="EmployeeSal"/>
     </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

**Table Structure**

**employee_1**

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | b    |
+------+------+
```

**employeesal**

```
+------+------+
| id   | sal  |
+------+------+
|    2 |   25 |
+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

i give you some example code for one to one relationship please go through it and let me kn if some problem ....
i have 2 tables 
1.Cart 
2.Representative 
my condition is , one cart is available only for one representative ...

Cart.java

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name=REPRESENTATIVE_ID)
    private Representative representative;

    public Representative getRepresentative() {
        return representative;
    }

    public void setRepresentative(Representative representative) {
        this.representative = representative;
    }
```

Representative.java

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="representative", cascade=CascadeType.MERGE , fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Carts carts;


    public Carts getCarts() {
        return carts;
    }

    public void setCarts(Carts carts) {
        this.carts = carts;
    }
```

Please go through it and let me know if any problem .

Comment: Thank you for relply me. Your code also gives all recods .i.e Hibernate show query prints left outer join

Comment: I want to excute inner join  .ie fetch the records from two tables having same ID